# Loading an image before pdf appears on target="_blank" new tab

Tags: image, pdf, tabs, loading

I am creating and displaying a PDF file which happens after I click a certain button. This all happens in a new tab **(target="_blank")**, and is all coded server-side.

How can I put a "loading image" when the new tab opens to show that yes a PDF file is being created, please wait.

Thank you and all suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Rather then link directly to the PDF, create an HTML "wrapper" in which you put an object tag whose style allows it to cover the entire window. You can then put a standard loading gif (or whatever) on top. Using the object onload event, hide the loading image when the PDF is loaded. Then use JavaScript to set the data property of the object tag to the PDF.